# Dynamically Allocated Structures

Tags: c++, structure, dynamic-allocation

So i am having troubles here.  The program works perfectly fine when i enter in 1 for numStudents but get a segmentation fault: 11 when i enter anymore that 1 for numstudents. Am i doing something wrong with the dynamic allocation?  I am just lost have done everything i can think of.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//Structure Declaration
struct Student
{
    string name;
    long long ID;
    double *score;
};

//Function prototypes
void calcAvg (int loc, Student test[], double average[], int tests);

int main()
{
    int numStudents, numTests;  //Get from user
    double  *averages;  //For Dynamic allocation of averages
    Student *info;  //For Dynamic Allocation

    cout << "Enter the number of students you will enter ";
    cin >> numStudents;

    info = new Student[numStudents];
    averages = new double[numStudents];

    cout << "\nEnter the number of tests that were taken by the students ";
    cin >> numTests;

    info->score = new double[numTests];

    for(int s = 0; s < numStudents; s++)
    {
        cout << "Enter student #" << (s+1) << "'s name ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, info[s].name);
        cout << "Enter " << info[s].name << "'s ID number ";
        cin >> info[s].ID;
        cout << endl;

        for(int t = 0; t < numTests; t++)
        {
            cout << "\nEnter " << info[s].name << "'s score for test #" <<(t+1) << " ";
            cin >> info[s].score[t];

            while(info[s].score[t] > 100 || info[s].score[t] < 0)
            {
                cout << "The score you entered is invalid, try again. ";
                cin >> info[s].score[t];
            }
        }

    calcAvg(s, info, averages, numTests);
    }

    return 0;
}


void calcAvg (int loc, Student test[], double average[], int tests)
{
    double total = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < tests; i++)
    {
        total += test[loc].score[i];
    }
    average[loc] = total/tests;

    cout << average[loc] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to repeat this for each student

```
info->score = new double[numTests];
```

So you could move it into the loop:

```
for(int s = 0; s < numStudents; s++)
{
   info[s].score = new double[numTests];
   ...
}
```

But all this is very error prone - I suggest you look into structures that can handle all this for you like `std::vector`.

Comment: That didnt work, still got the same segmentation fault.  And this is for a class and we arent supposed to use anything like the std::vector i believe.  I have had other people look at this as well and they dont see anything wrong with it and neither do I... so not sure

Comment: @JordanMcPeek: Not only does this answer make sense, but I just tested it, and it works. With your original code, I get a segfault if I enter more than 1 student. Removing your `info->score = new double[numTests];` and adding `info[s].score = new double[numTests];` to the top of the loop, it runs successfully to the end. So… if it isn't working for you, you almost certainly did something wrong. Post the actual code you're testing and where it fails.

Comment: oops i think i realize what i did, i just copied the info->score into my loop and didnt put info.score

Comment: It works fine for me using Michael Anderson's fix (see [here](http://ideone.com/OrQw4N) for 3 students). What I find a little funny about the design is that the average is kept separate from the structures, although it is only an average _for every student_, not a global one. But maybe you have to do it like this because of some detail in your assignment we don't know.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help, after that fix i was able to finish my program.